# OpenGL texture fuzzy

Tags: opengl, textures, sketchup, wavefront

I'm using OpenGL to render this cereal box but the textures look messed up (see below). When I change the view just a little bit, the way it's messed up is changed. What do you think is causing the problem?

[image: Image two]
[image: Image one]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible reason #1 (IMO most likely): duplicated geometry. I.e. in your scene, you're rendering 2 boxes with the exact same coordinates, one is gray, another one is textured.

Possible reason #2: wrong mipmaps. I.e. you've specified  e.g. GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST filtering, but you've forgot to load/generate all the mipmap levels of your texture.

Possible reason #3: your render target is 8 bits per pixel.

Comment: Wow, I think you're right with reason #1! I'm exporting this model via Sketchup into an .obj file and loading it into OpenGL. So it appears that either this model was created incorrectly or Sketchup is exporting it incorrectly... I'm using [this model by the way](http://sketchup.google.com/3dwarehouse/details?mid=f7d9d34e3d74d0c739f3410d5f76299b&prevstart=0). Can anyone verify that exporting this model into an .obj file from Sketchup also gives them duplicated geometry?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have sketchup, nor any other 3D model viewer. Quick way to diagnose - create a completely (or almost) transparent image in Photoshop/Paint.NET, replace the texture with that transparent image, and take a look at your scene.